# How can I get people to like me?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I recall in Oblivion there was a speechcraft circley-type-thing that you could use to get people to like you more. Is that in Skyrim?

Or is there another way to get people to like me more?

Comment: complete quests for them.

Comment: The love life is so bland, the life of a single is where it's at.

Comment: Real life - Getting people to like me (enough to get married)?

Comment: The only difference in Skyrim Speech is that you need to persuade someone about something that's diff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The speechcraft circle isn't in Skyrim, sadly.

However, if the npc has quests, completing them increases their disposition towards you. I believe there is also a disposition increase if you are a member of their faction (such as the theives guild, etc).

Keep in mind not all npcs can be married. Some of them appear to have conditions for being marriageable, and you can see those [at the UESP page for marriage.](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Marriage)

Comment: The entire game seems to have been made a lot simpler compared with Oblivion. For the console owners?

Comment: @Konerak Both Morrowind and Oblivion were released on Consoles as well as PC -  and in fact, outsold their PC counterparts, at least early on (long tail sales may have changed that, given the depth of the mod community for these games.) As to Skyrim being 'simpler', I'd say that it's a mixed bag. Some mechanics, like crafting, and skills themselves, have substantially more depth. Others have been streamlined, in part because they were often more [annoying](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Efficient_Leveling)than actual compelling gameplay elements.

Answer (score 4):

And do not forget that you have to wear an [amulet of mara](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Amulet_of_Mara) if you want the option to marry someone to appear in the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a mission for the person you like, they may or may not like you back yet.

After you do the mission for that special someone, have an Amulet of Mara ready. You will need to wear the amulet if you wish for the marriage dialogue to appear.

If you do not have an Amulet of Mara, you can buy one for 200 gold at the Temple of Mara in Riften.

The Amulet can be found at other places though the safest bet is at the temple of Mara for 200 gold.

Comment: It's better if you do the quest, "The Book of Love" from Dinya Balu at The Temple of Mara in Riften, to get the Amulet of Mara because then you also get the greater power "Agent of Mara" which gives you  permanent +15 resist magic.

Comment: @desaivv don't ask don't get!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the temple of Mara is where you find the amulet. I love it, but I haven't yet come upon someone like me on the game. I think it's because of my race being one of the khajiit or however you spell it. It's really fun to do side missions and get people to like you. I want the girl in the companions that's who I'm going for.